# can't import a scala class to my java code

Tags: java, scala

I tried to

> import com.twitter.finagle.service.RetryPolicy$;

however ant complains that it cannot find symbol
. I do have this class in my library:

```
com/twitter/finagle/service/RetryPolicy$$anon$1.class
com/twitter/finagle/service/RetryPolicy$.class
com/twitter/finagle/service/RetryPolicy$$anonfun$backoffJava$1.class
com/twitter/finagle/service/RetryPolicy.class
com/twitter/finagle/service/RetryPolicy$$anonfun$1.class
```

I can import the class without the dollar sign though. Is there some scala magic I didn't figure out? Thanks!

> import com.twitter.finagle.service.RetryPolicy;

Answer (score 0):

You're sure you're not getting an error because of a dependency RetryPolicy$ needs to resolve?

Can you include the actual error message?